# I'm having problems accessing functions on the parent object when using the a TimerEvent listener

Tags: flash, actionscript, timer, parent-child, event-listener

Using the below function worked fine before, when they were in a MouseEvent.

```
    public function jumpUIGo(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        this.parent.removeScene();
        this.parent.loadMapData(this.parent.systemDestination);
    }
```

But now that this code is connected to a timer, I get a method, property or null object reference error. The code below is what I made:

```
    private var jumpTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

    public function loadDestination(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        this.parent.removeScene();
        this.parent.loadMapData(this.parent.systemDestination);
    }

    public function jumpUIGo(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        this.parent.player.y = this.parent.coilGate_mc.y;
        this.parent.player.x  = this.parent.coilGate_mc.x;
        this.parent.player.rotation = this.parent.coilGate_mc.rotation + 90;
        this.parent.player.sS = 90;
        jumpTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loadDestination);
        jumpTimer.start();
    }
```

It does some stuff with the player (MovieClip) and then adds the event listener, and starts it. However, even thought the two functions were not null before, they are now that they are in the TimerEvent function.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong, or how I could work around this?

Comment: Adding the timer is irrelevant. Your error is most likely caused by something else. Is your class inheriting from display object and therefore using display objects parent property? That is your `this.parent` is a display object reference and not returning a class you created. The reason why I ask is because you are attempting to access properties and functions of what could potential be a `DisplayObjectContainer`, which will not have members and methods like `removeScene()` , `loadMapData()`, `player`, etc. (which should give errors if you attempt to do so).

Comment: I don't quite understand what the DisplayObjectContainer is. The reason I thought it would be the timer event that caused the error is because it worked fine when I didn't use the timer event, and instead use a mouse event. this.parent refers to code on the timeline, is that a DisplayObjectContainer (since it contains display objects?).

Comment: DisplayObjectContainer inherits from DisplayObject, basically any MovieClip or Sprite you create is a DisplayObjectContainer. I think it is safe of me to assume that is what your parent object is. In which case if all you did was create the MouseEvent and then switch to a Timer, then it is odd you didn't get an error earlier. My previous comment still stands. If you are looking to access code on the timeline try `MovieClip(parent).removeScene()` etc...the key being use `MovieClip(parent)` instead of `this.parent`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `this` means a different thing when listening to the TimerEvent.

Can you try both of your code snippets, the original with MouseEvent and the latter with TimerEvent, with the following two lines of code added;

```
    trace("handler detected an event of type: " + e.type); 
    trace("the this keyword refers to: " + this);
```

So...

```
public function jumpUIGo(e:MouseEvent)
{
    this.parent.removeScene();
    this.parent.loadMapData(this.parent.systemDestination);
    trace("handler detected an event of type: " + e.type); 
    trace("the this keyword refers to: " + this); 
}
```

And...

```
private var jumpTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

public function loadDestination(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    this.parent.removeScene();
    this.parent.loadMapData(this.parent.systemDestination);
    trace("handler detected an event of type: " + e.type); 
    trace("the this keyword refers to: " + this); 
}

public function jumpUIGo(e:MouseEvent)
{
    this.parent.player.y = this.parent.coilGate_mc.y;
    this.parent.player.x  = this.parent.coilGate_mc.x;
    this.parent.player.rotation = this.parent.coilGate_mc.rotation + 90;
    this.parent.player.sS = 90;
    jumpTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loadDestination);
    jumpTimer.start();
}
```

... and then copy and paste your trace output?